# How to set background color for BottomNavigationBar

Tags: flutter

I am struggling to set a background color and selected item color for `BottomNavigationBar`.

This is my Widget:

```
Widget BottomMenu(selectedIndex, onItemTapped) {
  return BottomNavigationBar(
    type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
    items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
      BottomNavigationBarItem(backgroundColor: Colors.indigo, icon: Icon(Icons.search), title: Text('Search')),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.location_searching), title: Text('Settings')),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.message), title: Text('Messages')),
    ],
    currentIndex: selectedIndex,
    fixedColor: Colors.redAccent,
    onTap: onItemTapped,
  );
}
```

However this is not working. All I get is white background with red font and icons. I want the whole navigation bar to be in indigo color.

Anyone?

Comment: still looking the solutions for the same problem dude. when you give them a Theme, its only give them a color for all bar.
you cannot give different background color for each icon.

Answer (score 1):

For background color. You can use Theme widget to wrap your BottomNavigationBar. And set canvasColor in the ThemeDate. Here is the code you want.

```
bottomNavigationBar: Theme(
        data: ThemeData(
          canvasColor: Colors.lightBlue
        ),
        child: BottomNavigationBar(

        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
              icon: Icon(Icons.search),
              title: Text('Search')),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.location_searching), title: Text('Settings')),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.message), title: Text('Messages')),
        ],
        fixedColor: Colors.redAccent,
      ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to change bottom navigation bar background color.

```
return BottomNavigationBar(
  type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
  backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
  onTap: (value) {
    
  },
  selectedItemColor: HexColor(iconColor[0]),
  unselectedItemColor: HexColor(iconColor[1]),
  items: [
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
    ),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
    ),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
    ),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
    ),
  ],
);
```

Add colors to your theme like that.

class ThemeDataConfig {
ThemeDataConfig._();

```
  static final ThemeData lightTheme = ThemeData(
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: HexColor("${Constants.backgroundColorLight}"),
    backgroundColor: HexColor("#"),
    brightness: Brightness.light,
    textTheme: lightTextTheme,
    primaryColor: HexColor("#"),
    accentColor: HexColor("#"),
    cardColor: HexColor("#"),
    bottomAppBarColor: HexColor("#").withOpacity(.25), // bottom Nav bar pop up color
    buttonColor: HexColor("#"),// Button Border Color used in bottom nav button
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same the issue. One thing you can do is create a color as a `const` and then use it in `backgroundColor` in the items:

```
const kBottomBarColor = Colors.green,
```

And then you can use it in icons `backgroundColor`:

```
BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.search),
        label: 'Business',
        backgroundColor: kBottomBarColor,
      ),
```